Accesing only one row/element of a df/array stored in Azure Blob from an Azure Function
I have a pretty big df/np array stored in Azure blob storage and I am wondering if I can access just certain rows of it without loading the whole thing into memory. This df/array is a cosine similarity matrix of 8GB and I want to query just one of its rows ( I know the index) from an Azure Function.
On a local environment I have been able to succesfully do this but so far I have been unable to do so with files stored in Azure as every attempt ends up loading the whole blob to memory somewhere (and that of course means that the Azure function takes forever to get a result).
Is this even possible? Any tips/ideas in case it is?
Both this:
with h5py.File('pathtofile', 'r') as f:
    product_index = 9  
    product_similarities = f['cosine_similarity'][product_index, :]

And this:
cosine_sim_matrix = np.load('pathtofile', mmap_mode='r')
product_index = 9
product_similarities = cosine_sim_matrix[product_index, :]

Seem to work ok locally (actually on Google colab so not even a real local PC) but no chance with Azure stored file.

You have to load it and then only one can access the file or blob from Azure:
In local you can simple use:
import numpy as np

rp = 'C:/Users/bojja/Downloads/test.npy'
test = np.load(rp, mmap_mode='r')
rith_rw_index = 9
ss = test[rith_rw_index, :]
print(f"Hello Rithwik, the row : {rith_rw_index}: {ss}")

If Blob is in Azure Storage then you have to use blob clients if you are using Function other than blob trigger.
import logging
import numpy as np
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
import tempfile
import os
import azure.functions as func


def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    ri_cs = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=rithwik98;AccountKey=k6xRKw1rithyrJpX3KwvtKjchoUw==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"  
    ri_cn = "rithwik"
    ri_bn = "test.npy"
    blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(ri_cs)
    rbc = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=ri_cn, blob=ri_bn)
    ds = io.BytesIO()
    rbc.download_blob().readinto(ds)
    ds.seek(0)
    test = np.load(ds)
    ri = 9
    spr = test[ri, :]
    print(f"Row {ri}: {spr}")
    return func.HttpResponse("Hello",status_code=200)

You can also use temporary file and then delete it after the function executes.
Output:


Hi RithwikBojja,
I am aware of how to operate with the blobs, I just wanted confirmation that the same operation that can be done locally to access one row of a df cannot be done in the "cloud environment". From you answer I get that no, this is not possible  as Azure requires you to download the whole Blob to memory (somewhere) and then you can operate with it. Is thi s assumption correct?
thanks!

Yes, you are correct.

Thanks for the help!
